# Derivative of cross entropy proof

Tags: calculus, optimization, machine-learning, backpropagation

#### Given the following definition of the loss function $L_{CE}$:

---

[image]

---

#### Here's my attempt for gradient w.r.t $W$, which is wrong. Where did I make the mistake?

[image]